# Why does `std::string` have a `find` member function?

Tags: c++, string, stl, stdstring

Why does `std::string` have a `find` member function while `std::vector` and friends don't have it?

Is there anything wrong with using `std::find` on the string?

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Comment: @juanchopanza wow that is an awesome link.  Just learned a lot about how nonmember friends can improve encapsulation.. (for those who didn't read the author argues that many member functions can be removed from classes, such as empty from std::list, std::vector, std::string and made into one generic function that serves the whole standard library).

Answer (score 12):

That is mostly for historical reasons, but not only.

The String Library and the STL (which is the container/algorithm library developed by A. Stepanov that ended up being part of the C++ Standard Library) were developed independently, and they adopted different conventions.

However, since they eventually both converged into the C++ Standard Library, the C++ Standard does make an effort to unify these syntactic conventions and allows using `string`s with STL algorithms, which is why class `string` has member functions such as `begin()` and `end()` apart from other member functions such as `substr()`.

Apart from backward compatibility, anyway, there is another reason why `string` provides member functions such as `find()`: unlike containers, which are meant to work with generic algorithms that access or manipulate their *elements*, strings are mostly thought of as values themselves rather than as *collections* of values (i.e. sequences of `char`s). Thus, it makes sense to encapsulate algorithms that manipulate `string` values into member functions of the `string` class.

In its design, the C++ Standard Library therefore supports both of these views of `string`s: as collections of values and as values themselves.

**UPDATE:**

The bit of your first sentence "while `std::vector` *and friends* don't have it" is not completely correct. At least, not if you extend `std::vector`'s range of friends to `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::unordered_set`, and `std::unordered_map` (in other words, pretty much to all of the associative containers in the C++ Standard Library).

Certain data structures do indeed have a member-function version of some generic STL algorihtms on their interface: this is either to indicate the fact that those algorithms have a more efficient implementation than their generic counterparts for those particular data structures (e.g. `find()`), or that a specialized implementation is necessary because the generic algorithms cannot be applied at all to those data structures (e.g. `std::remove()`, which *modifies* the values in the container).

Answer (score 4):

The semantics of `std::string::find` <sup>(*)</sup>are completely different from the semantics of `std::find`. In the case of the algorithm, it will find an element inside the container, which if you apply to a `std::string` means *find the location for which the character is X*.

The member functions `std::string::find` (except the one variant that takes a single `charT`) have a different purpose, they find *substrings* (i.e. a sequence of values rather than a single value).

The next question would be why that one overload that takes a `charT` is there, when it could be just a call to `std::find`. As Andy mentions in his answer, the implementation of the STL and the string libraries happened separatedly. Iterators were then added to the `std::string` component. By the time iterators were added to `std::string`, this overload was already there, even if it was not, the semantics are still a bit different from `std::find` in that as with the rest of the `std::string::find`, instead of iterators they take and return *positions*. This does not mean that one cannot be implemented in terms of the other, only that code would be more convoluted.

<sup>(*)</sup> Bear with me... read `std::string` as if it was spelled `std::basic_string<>`